# How can I use the new value calculated in one method to be used in another method?

Tags: java

I have update my code. I'm still having issues. I'm sure that there are better/easier ways to write this code, but I am only a few weeks into learning to program and the purpose is to use if/else if/else statements. What I am trying to do is take a value and unit of measure and then convert it to another unit of measure.

The first method: getSmallestUnit is supposed to convert any input into the smallest unit either inches or millimeters.

The second method; getNewUnitConversion is supposed then take the new value and convert it into the correct unit.

previous to this I have only ever had to use 1 or 2 variables. I have tried to return the variables in order to use them outside of the method, but it does not seem to be calculating from mm/in to the desired units.

I have no Idea where to look from here

```
 public class UnitConversion 
{

    private String input;
    private String output;
    private double value;
    private double temp;

    private double in, ft, mi, mm, cm, m, km;
    private final double inch_feet = 12;
    private final double inch_miles = 63360;


    private final double inch_millimeters = 25.4;
    private final double inch_centimeters = 2.54;
    private final double inch_meters = 0.0254;
    private final double inch_kilometers = 0.0000254;

    private final double millimeters_inch = 0.0393701;
    private final double millimeters_feet = 0.00328084;
    private final double millimeters_miles = 0.000000622;

    private final double millimeter_centimeters = 10;
    private final double millimeter_meters = 1000;
    private final double millimeter_kilometers = 1000000;

    public UnitConversion(String in, String out, double val)
    {
        input = in;
        output = out;
        value = val;
    }

    //Convert units to convert from (input) to its smallest form either in or mm
    public double getSmallestUnit()
    {
        if (input.equals("mi"))
        {
            in = value * inch_miles; 
            input = "in";
        }

        else if (input.equals("ft"))
        {
            in = value * inch_feet;
            input = "in";
        }

        else
        {
            in = value;
            input = "in";
        }

        if (input.equals("km"))
        {
            mm = value * millimeter_kilometers;
            input = "mm";
        }

        else if (input.equals("m"))
        {
            mm = value * millimeter_meters;
            input = "mm";
        }

        else if (input.equals("cm"))
        {
            mm = value * millimeter_centimeters;
            input = "mm";
        }

        else
        {
            mm = value;
            input = "mm";
        }
        return in + mm;
    }

    //Convert in or mm to desired unit of measurement
     public double getNewUnitConversion()
    {
        //convert from english standard
        if (input.equals("in"))
        {
            if (output.equals("ft"))
            {
                ft = in * inch_feet;
            }
            else if (output.equals("mi"))
            {
                mi = in * inch_miles;
            }
            else if (output.equals("mm"))
            {
                mm = in * inch_millimeters;
            }
            else if (output.equals("cm"))
            {
                cm = in * inch_centimeters;
            }
            else if (output.equals("m"))
            {
                m = in * inch_meters;
            }
            else if (output.equals("km"))
            {
                km = in * inch_kilometers;
            }  
            else if (output.equals("in"))
            {
            }  
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("Error: Must enter linear unit of measure in, ft, mi, mm, cm, m, or km");
            }
        }
        //convert from metric
        else
        {
            if (output.equals("cm"))
            {
                cm = mm * millimeter_centimeters;
                System.out.println(cm + "cm");
            }
            else if (output.equals("m"))
            {
                m = mm * millimeter_meters;
                System.out.println(m + "m");
            }
            else if (output.equals("km"))
            {
                km = mm * millimeter_kilometers;
                System.out.println(km + "km");
            }
            else if (output.equals("in"))
            {
                in = mm * millimeters_inch;
                System.out.println(in + "in");
            }
            else if (output.equals("ft"))
            {
                ft = mm * millimeters_feet;
                System.out.println(ft + "ft");
            }
            else if (output.equals("mi"))
            {
                mi = mm * millimeters_miles;
                System.out.println(mi + "mi");
            }
            else if (output.equals("mm"))
            {
                System.out.println(mm + "mm");
            }
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("Error: Must enter linear unit of measure in, ft, mi, mm, cm, m, or km");
            }
        }
        return in + ft + mi + mm + cm + m + km;
    }
}
```

Here is my main

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LinearConversion 
{
    //==================MAIN================
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner newConversion = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a linear unit to convert from: ");
        String fromUnit = newConversion.next();

        System.out.print("Enter a linear unit to convert to: ");
        String toUnit = newConversion.next();

        System.out.print("Enter a value: ");
        double value = newConversion.nextDouble();

        UnitConversion timsConversion = new UnitConversion(fromUnit, toUnit, value);

        timsConversion.getSmallestUnit();

        double conversion = timsConversion.getNewUnitConversion();
        System.out.println(conversion);

    }
}
```

Comment: Which part you have issue?

Comment: Just `return` the calculated value in `getUnit()`

Comment: Just return your value from one method and retrieve that value in another method( getUnit() ) by calling your method, which in this case is  your toString() method.

Comment: The logic you run in `toString()` is totally off and messes up your data. Further, a Java convention is that `toString()` returns a  string that represents the object - it's not supposed to do any calculations! Other than that: you have way too many parameters, your methods are too long and you also mess up in `getUnit()` by using `in` (which you messed up in `toString()`) instead of simply using `value`

Comment: A good advice would be to try and follow SRP (single responsibility principle) which means that in every method you're supposed to do only **one thing**! a better advice would be to read "clean code" by Robert C. Martin: http://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882

Answer (score 0):

The content you have in `toString()` is off. `toString()` returns a String representation of the Object. You should take that logic and put it in a different method. for `toString()` most IDEs can auto generate them. For instance in eclipse you can go `Source>Generate toString()...`

In your UnitConversion constructor you go:

```
public UnitConversion(String in, String out, double val)
{
    input  = in;
    output = out;
    value  = val;
}
```

You might want to check out the [`this`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) keyword. It refers to the current Object.

For instance:

```
public UnitConversion(String input, String output, double value)
{
    this.input  = input;
    this.output = output;
    this.value  = value;
}
```

If you want to use a variable calculated within a method, you should return it. There isn't much point of going `return 0;`